# Qt: HTML <select> tag (Dropdown) in WebEngineView shows up at an unexpected position, if the GUI gets rotated

Tags: qt, rotation, html-select, webengine

I just faced an interesting challenge in Qt, which I tried to solve for days now. I spent hours to find a similar problem on the internet, but with no success. In general, it's a simple GUI with a WebEngineView (based on QtWebEngine 1.4), which displays an HTML file with one dropdown (select) item, which should be rotated by 180° for an embedded device. But if the webengine is rotated, the content of the dropdown menu gets displayed outside of the webengine.

I created an SSCCE in Qt to provide you a "working" example. You could download the project with: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eafnl39jsrny4ro/dropdown_test.zip?dl=0

I did all following tests with Qt version 5.8 (Webengine based on chromium version 45) and Qt 5.9 (Webengine based on chromium version 56).

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <qtwebengineglobal.h>

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <qdebug.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Enabling makes Qt scale the main (device independent)
    // coordinate system according to display scale factors
    // provided by the operating system.
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    // contains the main event loop, where all events from the
    // window system and other sources are processed and dispatched.
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "platformName: " << app.platformName() << endl;
    // Current output: eglfs
    //
    // eglfs is a platform plugin for running Qt5 applications on top of EGL and
    // OpenGL ES 2.0 without an actual windowing system (like X11 or Wayland).
    // For more information, see EGLFS.
    // Other possibilities:
    // directfb or linuxfb

    // Environment variable QT_QPA_EGLFS_ROTATION doesn't work for QtQuick applications!
    // Qt Quick applications can apply transformations in their QML scene instead.
    // (But the transformation doesn't work for comboboxes/dropbdowns on a HTML website
    // invoked by the WebEngineView as demonstrated in file main.qml)

    // sets up an OpenGL Context that can be shared between threads.
    QtWebEngine::initialize();

    // provides a convenient way to load an application from a single QML file
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // load GUI
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    // enters the main event loop
    return app.exec();
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:red;">

<center>
<div>
    <p>This is the content of index.html</p>
</div>
<div>
  <select>
    <option value=1>Option 1</option>
    <option value=2>Option 2</option>
    <option value=3>Option 3</option>
  </select>
<div>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Version 1 (Of main.qml):
In the default landscape orientation, everything works fine and like expected.

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebEngine 1.4

Window {
id: rootWin
width: 1280
height: 800

  Item {
    WebEngineView {
            width: parent.width/4
            height: parent.height/4
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

            url: "qrc:/index.html" // HTML page with a <select> Tag to create the dropdown list
        }
    }
}
```

Version 2 (Of main.qml): (Try to rotate the WebEngineView on behalf of an Item)
If I rotate the "Item", in which the WebEngineView is located, the dropdown content gets displayed at an unexpected position (Even outside the WebEngineView area)

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebEngine 1.4

Window {
id: rootWin
width: 1280
height: 800

  Item {
  rotation: 180
      WebEngineView {
            width: parent.width/4
            height: parent.height/4
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

            url: "qrc:/index.html" // HTML page with a <select> Tag to create the dropdown list
        }
    }
}
```

Version 3 (Of main.qml): (Try to rotate the WebEngineView on behalf of a Rectangle)
If I rotate the "Rectangle", in which the WebEngineView is located, the dropdown content gets displayed at an unexpected position (Even outside the WebEngineView area)

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebEngine 1.4

Window {
id: rootWin
width: 1280
height: 800

  Rectangle {
  transform: Rotation { origin.x: rootWin.width/2; origin.y: rootWin.height/2; angle: 180 }
      WebEngineView {
            width: parent.width/4
            height: parent.height/4
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

            url: "qrc:/index.html" // HTML page with a <select> Tag to create the dropdown list
        }
    }
}
```

Could anybody tell me, why the content of my dropdown menu appears at a random position, if i rotate the parent object of my webengine?

Comment: From the Stackoverflow guidelines:

Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: Thank for your valuable intput, Jens. I just added some code snippets to my question to clarify. Maybe you are able to reproduce the problem and give me an advice?

Comment: Since it looks like, that this is a bug i reported it on the Qt bug tracker: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63888